# The automerge guidelines were not met -- Create Julia Package

Tags: julia

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5V4L.png)

Hi Every,

May I ask you why this will happen after I create a new Julia package, and register it to https://juliahub.com/ui/Home.

I think I already check the every steps very carefully, but still not figure it out where the bug comes from.

Can anyone tell me how to solve this problem? Many thanks!

Comment: 1. Please edit the question so we do not have the code as an image. We want to have your console output as a part of the question (use Markdown to copy-paste the code).  2. In your log you have a detailed information on what is wrong with your package.

Comment: you linked to the github actions logs; if you go to the PR itself, there should be a nicely formatted comment that explains what the issues for. For example, https://github.com/JuliaRegistries/General/pull/47142#issuecomment-948104922

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Pull Request that Eric mentioned which tells you exactly what went wrong:

https://github.com/JuliaRegistries/General/pull/48736

Quoting from there:

> - Name does not meet all of the following: starts with an upper-case >letter, ASCII alphanumerics only, not all letters are upper-case.
> - Name is not at least 5 characters long
> - Repo URL does not end with /name.jl.git, where name is the package name
> - Package name similar to 2 existing packages.
>
>   1. Similar to ALFA. Damerau-Levenshtein distance 2 is at or below >cutoff of 2.
>   2. Similar to BBI. Damerau-Levenshtein distance 2 is at or below cutoff >of 2.

Basically, `ABBA` is not a very descriptive package name, and the general registry favours unambiguous and self-explanatory names.

Now these are only **auto**-merge rules, which means that they prevent automatic addition of your package to the general registry, but not the addition per se. If you believe that there are good reasons why `ABBA` is the perfect name for your package and it should be registered under this name, just comment on the PR and it might get manually merged.

Comment: Thanks so much! I just modified package name.